# Finding coordinates of a vertex in a triangle (vectors)

Tags: vectors

The problem is the following: We have a triangle ABS with $AB = 4, AC = 5$, and $\angle B =90$ degrees. Place the triangle in a coordinate system with A and C on the first axis symmetric about the origin with A being to the right of C,and B above the x-axis. We can see that $A = (\frac{5}{2}, 0) , C = (\frac{-5}{2}, 0)$.  The problem is to show that $B = (\frac{-7}{10}, \frac{12}{5})$?

I have tried to find B by evaluating the length as the vectors but that does not give me any answer. I have also tried to find B by looking at the vector OB but that does not give me anything. I have also tried to use parametrization, but I dont get any solution. Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Hete let us consider B(x,y). So we know AB=$4$ so by distance formula $(x-\frac{5}{2}^2+y^2=16$  also by pythaoras theorem BC=$3$ so again $(x+\frac{5}{2})^2+y^2=9$ so now you have two equations thus you can solve for $x,y$ . Hope you can do the rest!

Comment: @ Eirik Your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be a point on the $x$-axis such that $BD$ is perpendicular to the $x$-axis.

Since $\triangle{ABC}$ and $\triangle{ADB}$ are similar, you can have
$$AC:AB=BC:DB$$
to get $DB$.

Comment: Nice trick. Thank you so much :)